# trouble accessing mssql db using perl and freetds on unix

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi, freetds

I'm trying to connect to a MS-SQL Database using perl and freetds. I have tested the installation of freetds using the unix commandline

```
`/usr/local/exec/bin/tsql -S myDB -I freetds.conf -U userName -P passw0rd -D DataBase1 -o q < query.sql`
```

where `query.sql` contains my sql query. It runs perfectly well. But when I try the same with perl it gives me the following error -

```
`Your sybase home directory is /opt/sybase. Check the environment variable SYBASE if it is not the one you want! Cannot access file /opt/sybase/config/objectid.dat`
```

but running

`$ set | grep SYBASE` yields `SYBASE=/usr/fsf/freetds`

Below is my perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl5/core/5.8.8/exec/bin/perl

use lib qw(/usr/perl5/core/5.8.8/exec/lib);
use lib qw(/usr/perl5/DBI/1.607/exec/5.8/lib/perl5);
use lib qw(/usr/perl5/DBD-Sybase/1.09/exec/5.8/lib/perl5);

use DBI;
use DBD::Sybase;

my $user   = "userName";
my $passwd = "passw0rd";
my $server = "myDB";

`export SYBASE=/usr/fsf/freetds`;
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/fsf/freetds/0.82/exec/lib`;
`export FREETDSCONF=./freetds.conf`;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBD:Sybase:server=$server", $user, $passwd, {PrintError => 0});

unless ($dbh) {
    die "ERROR: Failed to connect to server ($server).\nERROR MESSAGE: $DBI::errstr";
} 
else {
    print "\n";
    print "Successful Connection.";
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: which version of perl "perl -v" ?

Comment: The path to your drivers says 5.10. You might have downloaded the drivers for the wrong version of perl. Either update to 5.10.1 or get the drivers for 5.8.8.

Comment: thanks @AKHolland . I've corrected that. And that problem's gone but now it says `Your sybase home directory is /opt/sybase. Check the environment variable SYBASE if it is not the one you want!
Cannot access file /opt/sybase/config/objectid.dat` but running

`$ set | grep SYBASE` yields `SYBASE=/efs/dist/fsf/freetds`

Am i missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure about that... I'm going to post my previous comment as an answer, though, for anyone else who runs into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. Well, you need to first set the SYBASE environment variable before you install DBD-Sybase. And that's the reason behind `Your sybase home directory is /opt/sybase` when it is supposed to point to the freetds installation location. Ref: http://www.idevelopment.info/data/SQLServer/DBA_tips/Programming/PROG_4.shtml#Install%20DBD-Sybase

Answer (score 1):

The path to your drivers says 5.10. You might have downloaded the drivers for the wrong version of perl. Either update to 5.10.1 or get the drivers for 5.8.8.